# Drupal : form spammed but no form submissions

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, spam, drupal-forms

In despite of the few anti-spam modules I installed and configured, I still get a lot of spam in my mailbox from my Drupal site. The bots use a classic contact form, but the thing is, that there are no form submissions when I check the results page! Is it normal, considering they are bots?
I was thinking that they where perhaps using a google's cached version of the page.

Do you have any ideas? I don't know what to try or install anymore!

Comment: Are you using webform?

Answer (score 1):

Try using BOTCHA MODULE of Drupal. It is very successful in preventing the BOTS submissions.
https://www.drupal.org/project/botcha
Easy to configure also.

Comment: So I tried this and thought it was helping for a while but the spams are back now. I changed the destination mail to another email address but spams still go to the old email, so it seems like the contact form isn't even used by the bots anymore, even though the spam content looks like a form submission (with all the fileds filled).   How could I stop the spams from comming?